# Iterate over tds in ths in BS4 object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have BS4 object like this:

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe comparison_for_values">
   <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
         <th>System</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>value sum 1</th>
         <th>value sum 2</th>
         <th>value diff</th>
         <th>value diff in %</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>System 1</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>System 2</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>-240</td>
         <td>-244</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>-1.82</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>System 3</td>
         <td>10</td>
         <td>-261</td>
         <td>-245</td>
         <td>-16</td>
         <td>6.31</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to format last 2 `td` in each `tr` when value is different than 0 (by adding a `class` attribute). I don't know how to iterate over the `td`s in the `tr`s in tbody only without also changing the `th`s.

How to do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this - ```how to iterate over td in th in tbody only, I mean avoiding tr lines.```. I don't see any ```<td>``` inside ```<th>``` inside ```<tbody>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your beautiful soup object is called `soup`. Then you could achieve this with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
trs = soup.find_all("tr")
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    last_two_start = max(len(tds)-2,0)
    for i in range(last_two_start, len(tds)):
       if tds[i].get_text() != "0":
            tds[i]["class"]= "New_Class"
```

When you then look at `soup` via `print(soup)` you get the output:

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe comparison_for_values">
 <thead>
  <tr style="text-align: center;">
   <th>
    System
   </th>
   <th>
    Date
   </th>
   <th>
    value sum 1
   </th>
   <th>
    value sum 2
   </th>
   <th>
    value diff
   </th>
   <th>
    value diff in %
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    System 1
   </td>
   <td>
    0
   </td>
   <td>
    0
   </td>
   <td>
    0
   </td>
   <td>
    0
   </td>
   <td>
    0
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    System 2
   </td>
   <td>
    5
   </td>
   <td>
    -240
   </td>
   <td>
    -244
   </td>
   <td class="New_Class">
    4
   </td>
   <td class="New_Class">
    -1.82
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    System 3
   </td>
   <td>
    10
   </td>
   <td>
    -261
   </td>
   <td>
    -245
   </td>
   <td class="New_Class">
    -16
   </td>
   <td class="New_Class">
    6.31
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```